# Marcar mapa segun una busqueda

Tags: javascript

Tengo un archivo json con array de diversos puntos de ciudades y quiero situar los puntos en un mapa mediante un buscador sencillo.

Con un text input que me sirva como buscador de forma que al buscar por el atributo "name" del nodo "destino", y quiero situar ese elemento en un mapa.
¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

He hecho un mapa de imágenes y para acceder a cada zona quiero acceder mediante el atributo name. Utilizo `getElementsByName("nombre")` pero no sé de qué manera podría resaltar la zona elegida.

Comment: Y que has intentado? en SO no te lo van a hacer....

Comment: He hecho un mapa de imágenes y para acceder a cada zona quiero acceder mediante el atributo name. Utilizo getElementsBy Name ("nombre") pero nose de que manera podría resaltar la zona elegida.

Comment: @gabrielgomez Actualiza tu pregunta y escribe el código que haz escrito. Seguro que en poco tiempo obtienes respuesta.

Comment: Vale , he utilizado la api que me comentasteis de google map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que usar el recurso Geocoding del Api de google maps

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Con esto puedes obtener las posiciónes en latitud y longitud de una dirección en el mapa en varios niveles de precision y algunos datos adicionales, con esa información tienes que agregar un marcador en el mapa, para cada locación y en caso quieras que el mapa se centre en un lugar especifico debes llamar al método center del objeto que contiene al mapa.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple?hl=es